# Why sudo env is not showing all the environment variables?

Tags: bash, sudo, environment, env, sudoers

I have a variable set in a script file in /etc/profile.d/somescript.sh
I have modified the /etc/sudoers and added "ansible" user to the sudoers file like this:

```
Defaults !env_reset
ansible    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:   ALL
```

Why isn't the first line outputting anything ? why "sudo env" is not showing all environment variables (only partial)?

```
[ansible@ACEPP-LM-01 ~]$ sudo env | grep ENV
[ansible@ACEPP-LM-01 ~]$ sudo echo $ENV
PP
[ansible@ACEPP-LM-01 ~]$ echo $ENV
PP
[ansible@ACEPP-LM-01 ~]$ env | grep ENV
ENV=PP
```

Comment: You should ask these questions in http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I'd call superuser a valid location for this as well -- it's more a usage question than anything else. Indeed, though, it's certainly not a question about writing code, which is StackOverflow's domain.

Answer (score 0):

The files at `/etc/profile.d` are being sourced only at login shell. run the `sudo` with `-i` argument.

`sudo -i env | grep ENV`

You can read more [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) about the different `bash`invocation ways

Comment: How can I make sudo to run as "sudo -i" by default ?

Comment: As far as I know you can't. You can set an alias `sudo='sudo -i'` in your `.bashrc` file. But it depends on the way you are invoking the `sudo`, you should care either to source the `.bashrc` by yourself or to invoke the `sudo` within an interactive shell. Hope this helps you